# Content Version's Content Size

Tags: salesforcedx, files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

i am unable to pass values to Content Version's ContentSize Field.

i am getting this compile error:

**Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.ContentSize**

here is my sample code:

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert)
{
    for(ContentVersion cv : trigger.new)
    {
        system.debug('test--'+cv.ContentSize);
        cv.ContentSize=5000;
    }
}
```

please suggest what i am missing.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is being calculated based on the ContentBody. Any particular reason why do you try to set it?

Comment: @kurunve i am trying to resize my Image pixels.

Comment: Then you need to update ContentBody in order to do a resize. Just cutting it half would not help. It would be quite hard to do it with pure apex, so you might need to use callouts and 3rd party services, or build your own

Comment: @kurunve okay thanks for this suggestion.